# Real Methods to Evaluate $2 \int_{-1}^{1}x^2 \sqrt{1-x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I was recently contacted by a friend to find the values of the two following integrals by any means.

$$ I=2\int_{-1}^{1}x^2 \sqrt{1-x^2}dx$$

$$ J=\int_{-1}^{1}(1-x^2) \sqrt{1-x^2}dx$$

The first thought that I had was to do trig substitution, but I felt that would be somewhat messy. So I turned to contour integration and used [the dog-bone contour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9Um7.png) $C$ (where the circles of radius $\epsilon$ are centered at -1 and 1).

For $I$ this gave:

$$\begin{align*}
 0=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\oint_{C}z^2 \sqrt{1-z^2}dz&=I+2\pi i \cdot Res_{z=\infty}\left (  z^2\sqrt{1-z^2}\right ) \\ 
 &=I+2\pi i \cdot Res_{z=0}\left (  -\frac{\sqrt{1-1/z^2}}{z^4}\right ) \\ 
 &=I-\frac{\pi}{4} 
\end{align*}$$

Which implies that $I=\pi/4$.

Similarly one can find that $J=3\pi/8$.

---

I was satisfied with this result but I was disappointed that I couldn't think of any nice real methods to evaluate $I$ and $J$.

So now to my question, are there any methods of evaluation using real techniques besides trigonometric substitution that can give the values of $I$ and $J$?

I'm sure there are, I just can't think of any.

Comment: You know that $J + \frac{1}{2} I = \frac{\pi}{2}$, so if you have one, you have the other. You can (after using symmetry) make the substitution $t = x^2$ to get a beta function representation. Trig substitution actually isn't really messy too.

Comment: Trig substitution is the way to go. Why bother with contours?

Comment: @mvw: um, what? That doesn't even remotely address the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to compute both integrals you may exploit:
$$ \forall a,b>0,\quad \int_{0}^{1} x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}\,dx = B(a,b) = \frac{\Gamma(a)\,\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}, $$
where:
$$ \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\pi},\qquad \Gamma(z+1)=z\,\Gamma(z).$$

Comment: That's a good use of the beta function. Piecing this together with Daniel Fischer's comment gives a real technique  that satisfies my question.

Answer (score 3):

**hint**:$I = 4\displaystyle \int_{0}^1 x^2\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$. Let $x = \sin \theta, 0 \leq \theta \leq \dfrac{\pi}{2}$. Can you continue ? the same trick used for evaluating $J$.

Comment: This works nicely. For some reason I originally thought the trig sub would take many steps, but I guess I just didn't think about it too much. The only reason I didn't mark this as an answer is because I was looking for real methods other than trigonometric substitution.

Comment: That's fine and I am glad you get the desire answer....

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Change the variables: let $\sin t = \sqrt{1-x^2}$, $\cos t =x$ (then $dx=-\sin t \, dt$)... And use the Trigonometric integration ...